# What to observe if unknown coefficients exist?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I need to observe the solution of the following differential equation on oscilloscope
\$(\frac{dy}{dt})^2 - 2(\frac{dy}{dt})-3y= 5cos(2t)\$

This circuit is probably equal to the above equation, I double checked.

How do I determine \$C_{1}\$ and \$C_{2}\$ for the below solution?

\$y= y_{h} + y_{p}= C_{1}e^{-t} + C_{2}e^{3t}- \frac{7}{13}cos(2t) - \frac{4}{13}sin(2t)  \$

Normally, \$y(0)\$ and \$y'(0)\$ are given... but this time I don't know what should I observe?

Edit: Sorry for the mess in the topic. I didn't know what the best exponential  values to choose which provide us to observe that this kind of nonhomogeneus second order differential equation is correct.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your second term is correct? You have an increasing exponential, which in practice means your circuit is going to saturate somewhere, probably. I didn't bother solving the diff eq, but are you sure that 3 is not a -3?

Comment: Moreover, are you allowed to switch off the forcing term, i.e. the sinusoidal generator when you perform the test?

Comment: Yes. I realized now that -3t is better because it won't go to huge voltage.

For the second comment you wrote, as far as I understand,  voltage goes to zero as time passes. So you are saying is it okay for it to go to zero. 
Sorry I have some hardship in understanding english with terms.

Why would we need to switch off the sinusoidal generator?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that comment in a hurry, before reading your post more thoroughly. I forgot to delete it. Neglect it completely, it was prompted by a false idea I had of your problem.

Comment: As for the 3t exponent: did you actually check it is wrong? Of course "-3t would be better", but is that your real problem? Is this some kind of exam assignment or are you trying to solve a practical problem? This question seems revolving around old analog computers technology. Do you really need to determine those coefficients for a practical purpose?

Comment: This is a presentation topic of a lesson I need to pass.
I have to show that differential equations can be solved by analog computers,so I need to verify that a second order differential equation like this can be solved and observed. I think, it is okay even the solution is true for a short time.

Comment: That makes sense, now. Are you doing this only in simulation or are you planning to actually build the circuit? From what you say it seems you can choose the type of diff-eq. In this case, I'll advice to avoid rising exponentials if you need to perform accurate measurements. That's because in a real circuit you never know when a theoretical unbounded signal will trigger non-linear behavior in your opamps. And non-linear behavior in such a complex circuit is very difficult to analyze (depending on the specific opamp, you can get lots of nasty effects). So you will never be sure of your results.

Comment: Yes. I need to solve one of the y''+by'+cy =cost(a sinusoidal value must be here) type equation actually also.  Thanks. Then, I will choose a decaying exponential.

Answer (score 3):

The differential equation, with two negative coefficients, is unstable so you can expect positive powers in the exponential terms. Check for analysis errors. You can’t simply change the signs of the powers arbitrarily to fit what you believe to be the answer. I suggest you change all signs to positive in the differential equation.

In the op-amp circuit, you should use integrators rather than differentiators, and ensure the in/out signals of the integrators have the correct polarity; if not, invert as appropriate. Also, I can't see where the input cosine signal is applied.

Comment: As the OP said in his comments, he doesn't have to solve a well specified differential equations. So he really *can* choose which equation to solve (among complete 2nd order linear ODEs with constant coefficients with a sinusoidal forcing term). At first I had the same doubts as yours.

Answer (score 0):

If you can capture the transient in a time interval from t=0 to t=t1, with a suitable value of t1 (more on this later) you can substitute the readings of the scope as the value of y for those two instants in your formula, and this gives you a system of two linear equations with C1 and C2 as unknowns.

The problem is what is a suitable value of t1. In theory it should sufficiently small to avoid your increasing exponential swamping all the response. You would think that waiting a lot of time for that term to swamp the others would be good (i.e. sample when the e^3t term is the only one that is meaningful), but in practice you don't know when the real circuit will saturate, and this would introduce distortion in your theoretical signal.

Therefore, it is probably best to choose t1 so that the value of the e^3t is comparable in amplitude with the e^-t term.

Answer (score 0):

The point of making an analog of the system is to get a solution (a particular solution for specific values of constants, or a family of solutions) without knowing what it is.

I don't know why, but I can't make sense of your circuit. You have outputs connected to outputs and inputs to inputs. However, the usual way to do this to integrate, not use differentiators (which will increase noise and bandwidth).

Assume the second derivative term is available, and in your equation move everything else to the right of the = sign to see what to add to what. Integrate to get the dy/dt and again for the y term. Add them up with appropriate gains and add in the forcing signal. Send the result back to the first integrator - it is the d2y/dt2 term I assumed would be available. Turn it on and behold! The miracle of analog computing.

Your solution IS the oscilloscope trace. Y as a function of time.

Pull the solution y(t) from the output of the y term integrator. If you are actually making it, use integrator time constants to run 100 times faster than real-time or more. If you try 1 sec time constant the drift of most real op-amps will push the circuit to the rails rather quickly. Fiddle with the constants if needed to cancel input-offset.